# How does a gradle build know which modules have changed?

Tags: gradle

I want to write a bash script which grabs only the outputted jars for the modules within my project which have changed (after a build) so that I can copy them up to a server. I don't want to have to copy every single module jar every time, as in if you do a full clean build. It's a gradle project using git. I know that gradle can do an incremental build based on only the modules whose code has updated but is there a way this plugin (assuming it's a plugin) can be called? I have done some searching online but can't find any info.

Comment: Gradle uses internal cache (binary format, stored in `.gradle` folder). Using bash for copying the artifacts might be problematic but you can always implement a custom gradle task.

Answer (score 2):

Gradle has the notion of `inputs` and `outputs` that are associated with a task. Gradle takes snapshots of the inputs and outputs for a task the first time they run and on each subsequent execution. These snapshots contain hashes of the contents of each file. This enables gradle to check upon subsequent executions, if the inputs and/or outputs have changed and decide if the task needs to be executed again.

This feature is also available to custom gradle tasks (those that you write yourself) and is one way in which you could implement the behaviour you are looking for. You could invoke the corresponding task from a bash script, if needed. More details can be found here: 
[Gradle User Guide, Chapter 14](https://docs.gradle.org/2.5/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks).

Otherwise, I imagine your bash script might need to compare the modified timestamps of the files in question or to compute and compare hashes itself.

Answer (score 0):

The venerable [`rsync`](https://rsync.samba.org/) exists to do exactly this kind of thing: find differences between an origin and a (possibly remote) destination, and synchronize them, with lots of options to choose how to detect the differences and how to transfer them.

Or you could use [`find`](https://manpages.org/find) to search for .jar files modified in the last N minutes ...

Or you could use [`inotifywait`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to detect filesystem changes as they happen...

I get that getting Gradle to tell you directly what has been built would be the most logical thing, but for that I'd say you have to think more Java/Groovy than Bash... and fight your way through the manual.